# Angular $http.get fails when application contains token?

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to search about this problem to no avail I will explain the situation.

I have an angular app that can authentication usin jwt tokens which stores token in the header. When I am logged in to the app and I attempt to consume an external api(musicbrainz) I recieve a error 400.

If I am not logged in the request does work most of the time, sometimes I get 503 or 400 not quite sure if its something api related but essentially logged out request to api works.

I am assuming its related to x-access-token being set and my app using an http interceptor to detect token.

How can I get a api request while having the token in the header? Cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to be selective about when to apply the `Authorization` header (or whatever header you're using).

I suggest using some customised config logic in your interceptor, like this

```
request: function(config) {
  if (!config.external) {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '  + whatever
  }
  return config
}
```

Then, in your requests to an external API, simply add the following config

```
$http.get('http://musicbrainz.api', {
  external: true
})
```

---

An alternative would be to check the `config.url` and only apply the `Authorization` header to the appropriate services.

Comment: .config(function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');
  });

this is what i have in my app.js is that where i am meant to apply the above code?

Comment: @Elevant no, it would be inside your `AuthInterceptors` factory (or whatever it is)